# Haskell passing list as a argument doesn't work

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to pass a list with ordonable elements to a function

```
bsearch :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a -> Int -> Int -> Int
bsearch xs nr l h = if (nr < (xs !! ((l + h) `quot` 2) ))
                      then 0
                      else 1
```

But I get the following problem for when I call bsearch([1,2,3,4], 3 , 0::Int , 4::Int) from GHCi

```
<interactive>:280:8: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `[a]'
                  with actual type `([Integer], Integer, Int, Int)'
    * In the first argument of `bsearch', namely
        `([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 0 :: Int, 4 :: Int)'
      In the expression: bsearch ([1, 2, 3, 4], 3, 0 :: Int, 4 :: Int)
      In an equation for `it':
          it = bsearch ([1, 2, 3, ....], 3, 0 :: Int, 4 :: Int)
    * Relevant bindings include
        it :: a -> Int -> Int -> Int (bound at <interactive>:280:1)
```

I'm losing my mind here I dont understand why I did wrong.

Comment: That's not how you call a function in Haskell. `bsearch [1,2,3,4] 3 0 4` is what you want. You are passing a tuple as the first argument to `search`.

Comment: now it works thanks

Comment: Why is `bsearch` returning an `Int` instead of `Bool`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling Haskell functions, don't use the usual bracket-comma notation:

```
-- Correct:
function arg1 arg2 arg3

-- Incorrect:
function(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

The incorrect form is interpreted as passing a tuple (a set of values, like `(1,5,True)`) as one argument to the function.